# React Native : How to get device Screen Brightness and render it

Tags: react-native, screen-brightness

I`m creating an React App to display device Info. I want to render Screen Brightness level, not in Console. How do I do it?

```
DeviceBrightness.getSystemBrightnessLevel().then(function(luminous) {
    console.log(luminous)
})
```

I expected to render the screen brightness level, not to display in console

Comment: What do you mean "render" it? You mean display it in the view? You'd do it the same way as you display everything else asynchronous in React. Put the value into state with `setState` and then read the value from state in the render method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import DeviceBrightness from 'react-native-device-brightness';
export default class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
  isLoaded: false,
  brightness: 0,
};

}
componentWillMount() {
DeviceBrightness.getSystemBrightnessLevel()
  .then((luminous) =>{
    this.setState({
      brightness: luminous,
      isLoaded: true,
    });
  });
```

}

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
<Text style={styles.instructions}>{this.state.brightness}</Text>
 </View>
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
import DeviceBrightness from 'react-native-device-brightness';

export default class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      brightness: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    DeviceBrightness.getSystemBrightnessLevel()
      .then(luminous => {
        this.setState({
          brightness: luminous,
          isLoaded: true,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoaded, brightness } = this.state;
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return {/*loading view*/}
    } else {
      return (
        <Text>{brightness}</Text>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code is not working..Its showing brightness value is zero.

Comment: I added an arrow function in componentWillMount function, and code is now working. This is the changed componentWillMount function. Thanks for your contribution. componentWillMount() {
DeviceBrightness.getSystemBrightnessLevel()
  .then((luminous) =>{
    this.setState({
      brightness: luminous,
      isLoaded: true,
    });
  });